# Why does OPENSSH try to open C:\Windows\.ssh\authorized_keys instead of user directory?

Tags: openssh, sftp

Using OpenSSH for Windows, I'm trying to set up an SFTP using the public key.

My error log shows this:

```
12080 2020-03-20 11:51:02.136 debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Windows/.ssh/authorized_keys error:2
12080 2020-03-20 11:51:02.136 debug1: Could not open authorized keys 'C:\\Windows\\.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
```

In the sshd_config we have configured a user as follows:

```
Match User testuser
    ChrootDirectory E:\Integration\SFTP\TestUser 
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

So shouldn't the software go to E:\Integration\SFTP\TestUser\.ssh\authorized_keys for the key files?

Then as a test, I copied the users authorized_key to the c:\Windows..sh directory, then I got this error:

```
debug1: trying public key file C:\\Users\\testuser\\.ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys error:2
debug1: Could not open authorized keys 'C:\\Users\\testuser\\.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
```

When I put key in the above directory it worked.  So ChrootDirectory only works for the source of the files sent and received, not for the .ssh files? 
I will try removing from C:\Windows next...

I removed the file C:\Windows.ssh\authorized_keys, and it still works.  So maybe when  user is not found, it's going to the C:\Windows directory as a backup source for it?

Comment: @Robert System Service, and I restart it any time I change the config file.   Runs under Local System Account.  Was set up before I got here, for user/password SFTP.  Now they wanted to try a cert.

Comment: Posted issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1574

Answer (score 0):

I had situation with error "C:\Windows\.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory" when I did create User -folders manually instead of login with the actual user account.

My situation was fixed by:

1. renaming/deleting manually created user folders
2. login with the actual user account
3. creating/copying .ssh -folder and authorized_keys -file
4. checking the access rights of .ssh -folder and authorized_keys -file